# Synchronization in finding tuples satisfying given template

Tags: c++, synchronization, posix, shared-memory, semaphore

```
Tuple read(Template template)
```

gets a template of a tuple as parameter and returns a tuple satisfying the template from the buffer (shared memory).

```
void write(Tuple tuple)
```

writes a tuple into the shared memory. Read function should fall asleep when there are no tuples satifying the template in the shared memory. Write should awake first of sleeping processes, when adds a proper tuple.

What I already have:

```
Tuple read(Template template)
{
  Tuple result;
  down(empty);
  int uniqSem = register(template);
  down(buffMutex);
  Tuple *tuple = find(template);

  if(tuple != null_ptr)
  {
    result = *tuple;
    remove(tuple);
    up(uniqSem);
  }

  up(buffMutex);
  down(uniqSem);
  unregister(uniqSem);

  return result;
}
```

This wouldn't work when there were no tuples satisfying the template. Then the process would fall asleep and wouldn't get the result template. How could I reimplement the read function and implement the write function to make it work?